# To From animation to change grid size

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Require to change the size of grid animatedly form c#, i know To From animation is best for it, but have no idea how to do this, also suggest the better way if available

Comment: What do you have or what have you tried so far ..

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the size of the Grid using a To and From range values?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE - As i already mentioned above "i have no idea to animate" things from C#, till yet i had all the animations using Storyboards(in Silverlight)

Comment: @Gain- yes thats Exactly, with respect of time, say 500 ms

Comment: Is this a winforms application or WPF?

Comment: @ryadavilli - Silverlight 4.0

Comment: I have added the silverlight and silverlight 4.0 tags to your question for better clarity and greater visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Got it at MSDN

```
// Create a red rectangle that will be the target 
Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();
myRectangle.Width = 200;
myRectangle.Height = 200;
Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
myBrush.Color = myColor;
myRectangle.Fill = myBrush;

// Add the rectangle to the tree.
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myRectangle);

// Create a duration of 2 seconds.
Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

// Create two DoubleAnimations and set their properties.
DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();
DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation();

myDoubleAnimation1.Duration = duration;
myDoubleAnimation2.Duration = duration;

Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
sb.Duration = duration;

sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation1);
sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation2);

Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, myRectangle);
Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation2, myRectangle);

// Set the attached properties of Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top
// to be the target properties of the two respective DoubleAnimations.
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation2, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));

myDoubleAnimation1.To = 200;
myDoubleAnimation2.To = 200;

// Make the Storyboard a resource.
LayoutRoot.Resources.Add("unique_id", sb);

// Begin the animation.
sb.Begin();
```

Comment: Just change the target property from opacity to size